# Trouble Storing List of Lists in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-lists, storing-data

I made a wrapper function for an ode solver that outputs a list of lists:
1. parameters
2. controls
3. epi (list of dataframes for each desired output)

I need to test a lot of parameters and ultimately plot them side-by-side, but I have trouble storing the list. This is my code:

```
scale.factor.results <- list()

dem.scale.factor  <- seq(0, 1, by=.1)

for(i in (seq(from=0, to=11, by=1))) {                                
    scale.factor.results[i] <- get_model_results(dem.scale.factor[i])
}
```

This stores 11 lists but they seem to be with the parameters only.

I tried initializing an empty list of three lists:

```
scale.factor.results <- list(list(),list(),list())
```

but also only stored the parameters.

I looked up the lapply() function, but that doesn't seem to apply to this situation.

Comment: `scale.factor.results <- lapply(dem.scale.factor, get_model_results)` BTW: it is better to do `dem.scale.factor <- (0:10)/10`

Comment: can you unpack that a bit? i see it creates a list of eleven dataframes of the outputs, which is great, but i need to maybe somehow keep the param and control lists with each of those dataframes.

Comment: Eventually you are looking for something like `m <- lm(demand ~ Time, data=BOD); str(m); L <- list(m,m,m); lapply(L, '[[', "call")` Please refer to the documentation of the functions used.

Comment: did you mean "response ~ Time"? i don't understand what BOD is a stand-in for in your example. Also, Rdocumentation.org says lm() is for linear modeling. I don't understand how that's relevant to storing the list of lists. The model itself is nonlinear.

Comment: BOD is a dataframe which comes with R. Try it.